# How to shutdown gazebo from a plugin?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

how would one safely terminate gazebo from a plugin?

Calling `gazebo::shutdown()` kills it but not in a nicely fashion (errors appear in the terminal)

Thanks,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7112/how-to-shutdown-gazebo-from-a-plugin?/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2014-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/557/georg-bartels/) on 2015-01-07**:
Excellent question! I called gazebo::shutdown() from the UpdateCallback(...) of a ModelPlugin and it left the simulation in a frozen state without terminating gazebo. I can still press the buttons in the menu. Is this the intended behavior? (Ubuntu 12.04, Gazebo 4.1.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try sending a [SeverControl message](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/msg-api/4.0.0/server__control_8proto.html) to the `/gazebo/server/control` topic where the message has "stop" set to true.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/557/georg-bartels/) on 2015-01-09**:
This worked nicely for me, i.e. when starting the simulation with `gzserver` it terminates cleanly after the message was send. When started with `gazebo`, the server terminates cleanly and the gui remains. Thanks a lot! EDIT: I'd like to up-vote your answer but I do not have enough karma..